# Optimizing select top N query in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have query with sort and rownum to get top N record in big table (with more than 21M records). I use order and rownum for select n recent records like below. I defined index on nullable create_date column but the execution time was more than 30s. How can I improve this time?

```
select * from(
  select *
  from my_table t
  order by t.create_date
)
where rownum<N
```

Explain Plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name             | Rows     | Bytes       | Cost    | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                  |        9 |       31446 | 1153573 | 03:50:43 |
| * 1 |   COUNT STOPKEY           |                  |          |             |         |          |
|   2 |    VIEW                   |                  | 21335585 | 74546533990 | 1153573 | 03:50:43 |
| * 3 |     SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY |                  | 21335585 |  4544479605 | 1153573 | 03:50:43 |
|   4 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    |     MY_TABLE     | 21335585 |  4544479605 |  165097 | 00:33:02 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter(ROWNUM<10)
* 3 - filter(ROWNUM<10)
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Can you post the query plan?

Comment: Please append the explain plan - run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your-query` then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display)`, and copy a result of last query (as a plain text - don't take a printscreen) and append it to the question.

Comment: Please note that 11g is not a version identifier, it is only a marketing name used by Oracle. The version is either 11.1 or 11.2 (and often the *full* version number, as in 11.2.0.2.0, is relevant too). To find out the full version number, if you don't know it, you can run `select * from v$version`.

Comment: @trincot 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [first_rows](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#4942) hint.

FIRST_ROWS(n)

The hints FIRST_ROWS(n) (where n is any positive integer) or FIRST_ROWS instruct Oracle to optimize an individual SQL statement for fast response. FIRST_ROWS(n) affords greater precision, because it instructs Oracle to choose the plan that returns the first n rows most efficiently. The FIRST_ROWS hint, which optimizes for the best plan to return the first single row, is retained for backward compatibility and plan stability.

For example, the optimizer uses the cost-based approach to optimize this statement for best response time:

SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ employee_id, last_name, salary, job_id
FROM employees
WHERE department_id = 20;